# ASP.NET: Is it possible to inject CSS or Javascript into every page in my web app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, frameset, inject

I am working on a web application that uses a frameset instead of a master page.  I want to set up the app so that the background color of all pages is a light shade of red whenever I am debugging locally with a production connection string.

I came across one question here on StackOverflow where someone suggested creating a base page from which all page inherit, but I need a dynamic approach that just works without having to edit every page class in the application.  Switching over to use master pages at this point is not an option.

Is there a way to use global.asax or some other means to inject a style or script tag into the head of every document that loads?

Comment: theoretically yes, though i haven't seen someone put the effort into trying it ...

Comment: I answered my own question with a solution that actually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wooter wooter!

```
Private Sub Global_asax_PreRequestHandlerExecute(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRequestHandlerExecute

    Dim p As Page = TryCast(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Handler, Page)

    If Not p Is Nothing Then p.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(p.GetType, Guid.NewGuid.ToString("n"), "document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';", True)

End Sub
```

The key is to grab the page reference and then assign a startup script to it to add a style to the body element.  Basically, once you know how to get a reference to the page object, the sky's the limit.  Of course, a master page is always recommended for ground-up development, but this should get you some quick and dirty functionality if you ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a question a while ago asking how to force all pages to inhertit froma particular base page.
The answer came to late for me so I never tried it but check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689684/asp-net-can-i-force-every-page-to-inherit-from-a-base-page-also-should-some-of) post and some one said it should work.

The page it is pointing to is: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/06/08/766.aspx

Comment: Not sure this works.  First off, I just tried it and it doesn't work.  Second, several other people say it only works for pages with no codebehind.  To test this, I deleted the codebehind of a test page I created, and then it started working.  I don't think this web.config setting is designed to override a page's base class.

Comment: Ah, sorry! Was worth a try though. Thought it may help! Hope you find your answer!

Comment: I did about 15 minutes later and added it as an answer to this question.